# About one congruence

Tags: number-theory

Let k such that satisfy the congruence
$ k \overline{k}\equiv1\mod l$.
IF we know that:

$\frac{n}{(n,m)} \overline{\Big(\frac{n}{(n,m)}\Big)}\equiv1\mod \frac{m}{(n,m)}$

Could we say that:

$\frac{n}{(n,m)} \frac{\overline{n}}{(n,m)}\equiv1\mod \frac{m}{(m,n)}$

Comment: What does the $\bar{k}$ signify?

Comment: @Tobias, it seems to signify the inverse, modulo whatever modulus is in force.

Comment: I think if you try an example, say, $n=6$, $m=10$, you'll see what is going on, Aidas.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But then it does not make sense to assume that $k$ satisfies the congruence.

Comment: @Tobias, I think the question is poorly worded. I think the first sentence is only intended to introduce the overline notation for the modular inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:

Let $n=6$, $m=10$, so $\gcd(m,n)=2$, $n/(n,m)=3$, and $m/(m,n)=5$. If I have a correct understanding of the notation, then $\overline n$ must be defined so that $$n\overline n\equiv1\pmod{{m\over(m,n)}}$$ which is to say $6\overline n\equiv1\pmod5$, whence $\overline n\equiv1\pmod5$. But then $${n\over(n,m)}{\overline n\over(n,m)}\equiv1\pmod{{m\over(m,n)}}$$ becomes $${3\over2}\equiv1\pmod5$$ which is absurd.